# Wordpress .htaccess rewrite error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm having a problem with .htaccess file being over written.

Every now and then the site goes down with an internal error message. below is the .htaccess code that is causing the error. I'm assuming this is a plugin that is causing this error. to fix i need to delete the .htaccess and wordpress automatically adds new.

Has anyone come across this? Very bizare, any help will be Greatly appreciated.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
pt application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
# DEFLATE by extension
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: That line beginning with pt looks wrong remove that line.

Comment: You do not need 2 `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> ... </IfModule>` you can remove one as they can cause problem at a later time.

Comment: what is causing this to happen? it has happened three times in the last few weeks.